# Upload and retrieve file from blob storage

Tags: azure, image-uploading

I want to upload file in azure blob storage and retrieve that file in my own application.

My Code:

```
protected void btnUploadtoCloud_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         UploadFile();
}
public string UploadFile()
{
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString"));
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("vest");

        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExist();
        BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

        containerPermissions.PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container;

        blobContainer.SetPermissions(containerPermissions);


        CloudBlob blobText = blobContainer.GetBlobReference(fupPicture.FileName);
        blobText.Properties.ContentType = fupPicture.PostedFile.ContentType;
        string blobURL = blobText.Uri.ToString();
        blobText.UploadFromStream(fupPicture.FileContent);
        imgTest.ImageUrl = blobURL;
        return blobURL;
 }
```

But my problem is first line of UploadFile.I include image because  I want to show my ref  dll too.

[image: blob] .

Why error in `RoleEnvironment`. May i missing some thing to include.

Note : I have window azure account and I deploy other sites easily.

**EDIT**

After Gaurav suggestion  I try :

```
string cnn = "<add name=\"testconnectionstring\" DefaultEndpointsProtocol=\"http;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=A9Jlajksdh69szut9zOfsxWMD/qLaP3Gy6ID9mIarNmCDasdhlyNlAR9wV0NGjqJUZeM4x6x5bTumLv+1nC51clHDl5GTYYPA==" + " />";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(cnn);
```

but unable to work I got error invalid combination.

Comment: Where are you running this code? Is it in a cloud service or a regular web application?

Comment: regular web application.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because `RoleEnvironment` is only available when your code is running in context of a Cloud Service (Web Role) either in local compute emulator or in cloud.

Since it is a web application and I am guessing that you will be deploying it in an Azure Website, you can simply use `AppSettingsReader` to read from Web.Config file. Something like:

```
        var rdr = new AppSettingsReader();
        string connectionString = (string) rdr.GetValue("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", typeof(String));
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
```

If your application is connecting to a cloud storage account, your connection string would look something like:

> DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=your-account-name;AccountKey=your-account-key

For connecting to local storage emulator, your connection string would look like:

> UseDevelopmentStorage=true

Comment: may you provide sample connection string.I have not any database just want to upload image and get image in my site.

Comment: Updated my answer with connection strings. HTH.

Comment: So in your web.config appsettings section, you should put `<add key="testconnectionstring" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=A9Jlajksdh69szut9zOfsxWMD/qLaP3Gy6ID9mIarNmCDasdhlyNlAR9wV0NGjqJUZeM4x6x5bTumLv+1nC51clHDl5GTYYPA==" />` and then use the code I posted above to read this setting value.

Comment: U r perfect. Thanks.AppSettingsReader method works. Thanks a lot.